# Check if one of li doesnt have a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with this condition :
I have a series of li with a class, and I want to execute code if one of the li does not have this class.

For example :

```
<ul class="list-synthese">
 <li class="hidden">Lorem</li>
 <li class="hidden">Lorem</li>
 <li class="hidden">Lorem</li>
 <li class="hidden">Lorem</li>
 <li>Lorem</li>
</ul>
```

Here is what I want to do :

```
if $('list.synthese > li').hasNOTclass('hidden'){
 mycode;
}
```

Hope someone can help me !
Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:not` selector. also you have incorrect selector for ul element:

```
if($('.list-synthese > li:not(.hidden)').length){
  mycode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bad approach but working: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/13ophnqz/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.list-synthese > li').each(function(i, ele) {

    if (!$(ele).hasClass('hidden')) {
      alert('li number ' + (i + 1) + '  doesnt have class hidden')
    }

  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-synthese">
  <li class="hidden">Lorem</li>
  <li class="hidden">Lorem</li>
  <li class="">Lorem</li>
  <li class="hidden">Lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem</li>
</ul>
```